# Swift: inout with generic functions and constraints

Tags: swift, generics, inout

I am making my first steps in Swift and got along the first problem. I am trying to pass an array by reference using `inout` on an generic function with constraints.

First, my application start point:

```
import Foundation

let sort = Sort()
sort.sort(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

And here my class with the actual problem:

```
import Foundation

class Sort {
    func sort<T:Comparable>(items:[T]){
        let startIndex = 0
        let minIndex = 1
        exchange(&items, firstIndex: startIndex, secondIndex: minIndex)
    }

    func exchange<T:Comparable>(inout array:[T], firstIndex:Int, secondIndex:Int) {
        // do something with the array
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in Xcode on the line calling `exchange`:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

Am I missing here something?

**Update:** Added complete project code.

Comment: maybe post the actual code that is giving the error....

Comment: I added the complete projects code. The exchange function isn't actually doing anything with the array, so thats the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with following modifications:

- the array passed into it must be a var. [As mentioned in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173), inouts must not be let or literals.

  > You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because constants and literals cannot be modified.
- items in declaration must also be inout to indicate that it must be var again

---

```
import Foundation


class Sort {
    func sort<T:Comparable>(inout items:[T]){
        let startIndex = 0
        let minIndex = 1
        exchange(&items, firstIndex: startIndex, secondIndex: minIndex)
    }

    func exchange<T:Comparable>(inout array:[T], firstIndex:Int, secondIndex:Int) {
        // do something with the array
    }
}


let sort = Sort()
var array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
sort.sort(&array)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can "exchange" two values in an array by using the swift swap function.

e.g.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
swap(&a[0], &a[1])
```

would mean that `a` now is [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Yes, i know. But thats not the problem I asked for.